# Stopping the classloader leak when using log4j in JBoss

Tags: memory-leaks, jboss, log4j, classloader

We have an old version of JBoss running multiple apps and we get perm gen errors after multiple deploys. I believe it is due to a classloader leak.  It turns out that this is due to a bug that they have decided to not fix:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46221

The short and skinny of that link is that you get a classloader leak simply from using log4j and they aren't fixing it.

So is there a there a way for me to fix the classloader leak so I don't need to restart the server every two weeks?

I'm hoping to get around upgrading the server, but if I can change configurations, apply some sort of patch, or perhaps reset the log file somehow, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The Bug has an attached patch.  Did you try that? Going from jboss4 to 5 is not that painful, it would probably be easier to upgrade then to play around with a patch.